# Highstock: Can we rotate 90 degrees a candlestick chart?

Tags: highcharts, rotation, candlestick-chart

Using Highstock, I wish to draw a candlestick chart over a line chart.
I know it sounds weird, but I need to rotate the candlestick chart by 90 degrees clockwise.
The code I have now is:

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/new-intraday.json', function (data) {

// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


    title: {
        text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
    },

            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    
    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        type: 'candlestick',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    },{
        name: 'TEST',
        type: 'line',
        data: data
    }]
});
```

});

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Francois_G/71oc24gn/10/)

What I want to get is the following (something like...):
[image: Candlestick chart rotated and overlapping]

Any (simple) idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highstock is not adapted to this kind of customization. The only simple way seems to be creating two overlapping charts - one inverted and one with transparent background, but we have to take into account many limitations, like for example tooltip.

```
chart: {
  inverted: true,
  ...
}
```

---

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nb1jyaq5/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I don't need tooltip nor anything on the rotated chart, just the chart. Thanks a lot!